# calculate p-value from a confidence inverval

Tags: p-value, roc, auc

I recently stumbled over the note below and I wonder if there was a method to calculate a p-value for two AUC values with 95%-confidence intervals.

Altman Douglas G, Bland J Martin. How to obtain the P value from a confidence interval BMJ 2011; 343 :d2304 
available at:
https://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d2304

Let's say I have two AUC values from two correlated ROC-Analysis:

AUC1=0.80(95%-CI=75-85)

AUC2=0.92(95%-CI=0.88-0.96)

Is there any way to calculate a p-value if there is no raw data available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the linked statement is correct and two AUCs are independent, (for example from two different studies).

```
 Steps to obtain the P value from the CI for an estimate of effect (Est)
 (a) P from CI for a difference
 If the upper and lower limits of a 95% CI are u and l respectively:
    1. calculate the standard error: SE = (u − l)/(2×1.96)
```

Then you can two SE1 and SE2 from two CI1 and CI2. Then get a z=(AUC1-AUC2)/sqrt(SE1*SE1+SE2*SE2).

z follows standard normal distribution under the null hypothesis that true AUC1 = True AUC2. Then you can get the p value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Would this also be valid if the AUCs derive from correlated ROC analysis (two non nested models applied on the same population) as stated above?

Comment: No. Must be independent. Given your situation, I do not think you can get the p-value you wanted.